Implications of replacing the loopback interface in a network namespace with a tun device
I am running a process in a network namespace, and I want that process to be able to reach services running on localhost outside the namespace. I had the idea of deleting the loopback interface and replacing it with a tun device that proxies traffic to the loopback interface from outside the namespace. First: is this even possible in linux? Second: will this work in the way that I have in mind? Third, is there a better way to achieve this?
I am assuming that the process in the network namespace does not itself listen on any loop interface ports, and there are no other processes in the network namespace listening on the loopback interface.
